# insert timestamp into MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, iso8601

I am working on pulling some data in from a Rest-api into my MSSQL database. The issue I am having is the timestamp that I am being given from the api does not appear to be formatted correctly to just insert '2013-09-16T07:00:00+0000'.

example insert:

```
INSERT INTO [page_fan_adds_unique]([period], [title], [description], [value], [end_time])  
VALUES ('day', 'Daily New Likes', 'Daily: The number of new people who have liked your Page (Unique Users)','0', '2013-09-16T07:00:00+0000')
```

I know changing the format to 2013-09-16T07:00:00+00:00 works but I didn't want to have to manipulate the data before the insert.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no way around it. You'll have to reformat the data somehow. Id recommend STUFF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I did. from my PHP code I inserted that date [end_time] = CAST(STUFF('".."',23,3,':00')AS DATETIME2)"

Now when I write my "select" statements I just cast(end_time as datetime) I find that this is a lot easier than trying to cast a string into a datetime in sql.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this without formatting.

From the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) about **TIMESTAMP**:-

> Is a data type that exposes automatically generated, unique binary
>   numbers within a database. timestamp is generally used as a mechanism
>   for version-stamping table rows. The storage size is 8 bytes. The
>   timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not
>   preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime
>   data type.

You may use `datetime` data instead.

Comment: Thats what I thought but I wanted to see if anyone had any other ideas.Thank You for your response.